# Given this hash function, an expected output, and the length of the input string, how do I find the input string that returns the given result?

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering, brute-force, hash-function

I have this hash function below.

I know that for an input string of length 8 I get a hash with the value of 16530092119764772

The input string can only consist of the characters "abcdefghijklmnop"

What is the best approach to find the input string?

Is there a way to break down the problem mathematically without relying on a brute-force approach to find the string?

Would a recursive solution overflow the stack?

```
function hash(str) {

  let g = 8;
  let charset = "abcdefghijklmnop";

  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    g = (g * 82 + charset.indexOf(str[i]));
  }

  return g;

}
```

As an example for the string "agile" it hashes to 29662550362

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s not even really a hash, because `charset` doesn’t have 82 characters in it. It’s more like parsing a string as a base-82 number where you can only use the first 16 symbols. It’d be completely reversible if it didn’t use floating-point numbers, which are imprecise for integers that big. In case you’re not familiar with why, the simplified version is that the operation inside the loop:

```
g * 82 + d
```

gives a different result for every possible value of g and d as long as d is less than 82, because there’s enough space between g * 82 and (g + 1) * 82 to fit 82 different *d*s (from 0 to 81). Each different result is reversible back to g and d by dividing by 82; the whole value is g and the remainder is d. When every operation inside the loop is reversible, you can reverse the whole thing.

So, like you might convert a number to decimal manually with a loop that divides out one digit at a time, you can convert this imprecise number into base 82:

```js
const getDigits = (value, base) => {
    const result = [];
  
    while (value) {
        result.push(value % base);
        value /= base;
    }
  
    return result.reverse();
};

const getLetter = index =>
    String.fromCharCode(97 + index);

const getPreimage = value =>
    getDigits(value, 82n)
        .map(Number)
        .map(getLetter)
        .join('');

console.log(getPreimage(29662550362n));
console.log(getPreimage(16530092119764772n));
```

The results start with “i” because `g` starts at 8 instead of 0. The second number is also big enough to not be unique (in contrast to `agile`’s “hash”, which can be represented exactly by a JavaScript number), but if you were just trying to find *any* preimage, it’s good enough.

```js
function hash(str) {

  let g = 8;
  let charset = "abcdefghijklmnop";

  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    g = (g * 82 + charset.indexOf(str[i]));
  }

  return g;

}

for (const s of ['hijackec', 'hijacked', 'hijackee', 'hijackef', 'hijackeg']) {
    console.log(s, hash(s) === 16530092119764772);
}
```

Comment: As I try to wrap my head around your answer, I have a few follow up questions.

Lets say the charset was not in alphabetically contiguous order and was but was more like "acdefgkiloprstvy" how would that change your answer?

Also how do you explain the trailing n when your calling the getPreimage function?

So a 64-bit integer in the "hash" function would resolve the issue with imprecise floating point operation?

Comment: @nkoz18: If the charset is in a different order, `getLetter`’s implementation needs to change to index into it, like `'acdefgkiloprstvy'.charAt(index)`. | The trailing `n` means a BigInt. It’s a new JavaScript type with unlimited precision, not strictly necessary here (`getDigits` just needs to use `value = Math.floor(value / base)` to get integer division) but there’s really no reason not to use it beyond compatibility. | A 64-bit integer gives precise answers up to 9 characters, but collides again after that, and in a way that can make it harder (but probably not hard) to reverse.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand it, but your solution works. I am going to try to step through the code to understand how you got there. Can you recommend any reading on the subject? Googling "reverse a hash function" is not helpful because that is not what this is. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @nkoz18: Try understanding the equivalent problem in base 10 first. Cut the character set down to `'abcdefghij'` and change the multiplier from 82 to 10, then notice the relationship between your input and the hash. As far as reading material goes… I haven’t been able to find anything great yet, but there’s stuff like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111150/changing-a-number-between-arbitrary-bases, http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc110/inclass/conversions.html.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a recursive function that starts from 8, iterates over the charset indices and stops (returns) whenever the current value gets over the passed hash.

Check the comments below for more details:

```js
const charset = 'abcdefghijklmnop';

function bruteforce(hash, base = 8, result = {value: ''}) {
  // Always multiply the previous value by 82
  base *= 82;

  for (let i = 0; i < charset.length; i++) {
    // Add the char index to the value
    value = base + i;
    // If we found the hash, append the current char and return
    if (value === hash) {
      result.value += charset[i];
      return base === 656 ? result.value : value;
    }
    // If we went past the hash, return null to mark this iteration as failed
    if (value > hash) {
      return null;
    }
    // Otherwise, attempt next level starting from current value
    value = bruteforce(hash, value, result);
    // If we found the hash from there, prepend the current char and return
    if (value === hash) {
      result.value = charset[i] + result.value;
      return base === 656 ? result.value : value;
    }
  }

  // We tried everything, no match found :(
  return null;
}

console.log(bruteforce(29662550362));
```

Comment: The original problem had slightly different parameters and I refactored this solution to account for them. (bumped the digit in the loop down by one and the length of the input string up by one) I changed the base numbers in your solution to match the new requirements and ran it. It found a solution in about 30 mins. It came very close to the answer, but it was slightly off due to JS using an approximation for numbers that big. I noticed the word was close to an actual word and rewrote the hash in python which supports long and got the answer. The original problem was posed with 64-bit ints.

Comment: @nkoz18 Can you provide the actual parameters? I'd be happy to edit this answer accordingly. Though to be fair I'm not that versed in this sort of things (I can't understand much of the other answer, for instance), I just took it as a fun exercise :)